# To what extent do we need to state the types of variables?

Tags: real-analysis

My question is to what extent do I need to state the type of the variables. Is it up to intuition? Should I always state it?

For example for the definition of convergence to a limit I have:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfLPV.png

Is this correct? I have specified that N is a natural number, though have not specified that n is also a natural number. I have not specified that epsilon and l are real numbers. Can this be assumed?

This is my first time posting a question on math exchange, so if I have done anything wrong please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: It's always important to always clearly define what values a variable can take. You should never assume they are understood without being clearly stated.

Comment: You should probably add "for all real number $\epsilon > 0$" though truthfully, in some contexts it will be assumed that you're working with real numbers, such as a real analysis course. It never hurts to specify, though.

Comment: The term "variable" is often used but rarely defined.